# Резиновое позиционирование сторонних виджетов

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Доброго времени суток всем , у меня есть такой вопрос , делаю резиновую версию сайта.
Есть 2 виджета сторонних , курс валют и погода , автор предлагает виджеты с конкретной шириной и высотой по px , но так как я делаю сайт резиновый , то у меня вопрос , как же мне их адаптировать под резиновую верстку , чтобы они тоже позиционировались в процентах?
Пробовал добавить div с процентами , но на виджетах не пашет..
Есть идеи?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте удалить из `width=""` или `style="width"`, что там они используют.. И задать через CSS `.widget {width: 100%;}`. У меня так получилось сделать комментарии от VK резиновыми.

Comment: Поздно заметил.. Высоту изменить? Через JS высчитывать, или же через CSS `.widget {height: 5vh;}` - vh - это высота браузера типо.. Не уверен что она работает во всех браузерах.

Comment: да , сначала бы ширину хотябы поменять , а с высотой дальше повоюем

Comment: к сожалению, в коде только ссылка на javascript файл внутри самого сайта автора, так что ничего поделать не могу не с шириной не с высотой...

Comment: Дайте ссылку на сайт, пожалуйста.

Comment: http://www.pogoda.com/widget/?gclid=Cj0KEQjw1K2_BRC0s6jtgJzB-aMBEiQA-WzDMWMBYfeaJ_5rEdF4MAXG9zyGO3XWr0HW2kxcpaJDRlIaApC28P8HAQ

оттуда беру виджет

Comment: Применяйте `!important` к свойствам стиля. Имейте ввиду, там есть `iframe`, который должен быть резиновым, вот пример кода [ссылка](https://jsfiddle.net/CbIPoK2513/pLnpbrqv/)

Comment: вроде проверял , не совсем работало , вы проверили?

Comment: У меня FF, там всё работает. В принципе `!important` работает уже давно во всех браузерах, так что должно помочь.

Comment: спасибо большое , а можно еще вопрос?
не подскажете случайно . вот поставил я display:flex;
как сменить его высоту по пикселям , ато там отступы изза этого , читаю но не совсем ясно пока

Comment: С Flex'ами ещё не работал, так что не подскажу, извините.

Comment: Спасибо за все)

Comment: Попробовал так , как сказали , через !important задал width , но к сожалению никак не хочет менять размер ..
В чем смысл виджетов тогда , если они под дизайн не могут адаптироваться?